# Dimension of vector space over a field

Tags: linear-algebra

what is the dimension of $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} (\mathbb{C}^3)
 $?

I read in Wikipedia that  $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} (\mathbb{C})=1
 $ but how about 3 in Exponent?

Comment: You consider $\mathbb{C}^3$ as a vector space over a field $\mathbb{C}$, right? Can you proceed and find dimension just by definition?

Comment: Yes thats right. I would say 3 as Dimension

Answer (score 4):

More generally, if $K$ is a field, then $K^n$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $n$ (just note that the canonical basis has $n$ elements).